# In my Cargo.toml a crate I can use in the package I'm building is not found when used in build.rs How can I fix this?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to use the [`async-process`](https://github.com/smol-rs/async-process.git) crate/package in my build.rs file.

In the crates.io page it says I can put it in my project's `Cargo.toml` as:

```ini
[dependencies]
async-process = "2.0.1"
```

And in my rust code as:

```
use async_process::Command;
```

I can use it in my own package but it breaks the compile of `build.rs`:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `async_process`
 --> build.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use async_process::Command;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `async_process`?
  |
  = help: consider adding `extern crate async_process` to use the `async_process` crate
```

I then tried:

```
extern crate async_process;
```

And get this error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `async_process`
 --> build.rs:4:1
  |
4 | extern crate async_process;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

is it some restriction placed on `build.rs`?

The reason I want this is I am using the `build.rs` to spawn a command to run a rather long process and want to log it's `stdout` to a file (or print to the console while running) the `async-process::Command` offered a way to do this, that is if I can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Cargo Manifest

```ini
[dependencies]
```

are binaries and library dependencies (runtime).

As you are using `async-process` in `build.rs` script, there is another section you should use:

```ini
[build-dependencies]
async-process = "2.0.1"
```

Those dependencies are used for building your crate (compile time)

Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html